# Installing ffmpeg on elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install ffmpeg to elastic beanstalk, I have created config file with below commands-

```
packages:
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []
    ImageMagick-devel: []
commands:
  01-wget:
    command: "wget -O /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz"
  02-mkdir:
    command: "if [ ! -d /opt/ffmpeg ] ; then mkdir -p /opt/ffmpeg; fi"
  02-tar:
    command: "tar xvf /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz -C /opt/ffmpeg"
  04-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffmpeg ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg; fi"
  05-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffprobe ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4-64bit-static/ffprobe /usr/bin/ffprobe; fi"
  06-pecl:
    command: "if [ `pecl list | grep imagick` ] ; then pecl install -f imagick; fi"
```

Till 05-ln everything seems to be fine, but on 06-pecl I am getting below error-

```
[2018-03-08T08:06:29.390Z] INFO  [32014] - [Application update app-f8f2d-180308_133451@78/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_FranchiseSoft/Command 06-pecl] : Completed activity. Result:
  PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
  /bin/sh: line 0: [: 3.1.2: binary operator expected
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps you need to install ImageMagick before installing Imagick. Be sure to install ImageMagick 6 or 7, which ever is compatible with your other software, especially Imagick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, 04-ln and 05-ln were actually wrong, fixed it by-

```
  04-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffmpeg ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4.2-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg; fi"
  05-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffprobe ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-3.4.2-64bit-static/ffprobe /usr/bin/ffprobe; fi"
```

Comment: This does not provide enough context and hence cannot be a solution for others who are going to face the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not provide enough context about the solution.

So, here's a better explanation:

The URL used to download the .tar file - https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz - packages the latest version of ffmpeg. It is evident by the change in the directory name when the contents are extracted.

As of 9th December, 2022, the name of the folder has version 5.1.1. Hence, the 04-ln and 05-ln need to have 5.1.1. to create correct symbolic links.

In future, if a newer version is released, the symbolic links will be not created properly and the application will fail.

As one solution, you can use the following URL where you know the release version is fixed and so is the name of the folder in the tar. Eg: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/old-releases/ffmpeg-4.4.1-amd64-static.tar.xz

Or, you can simply host the file in your CDN which is more reliable as your deployment does not depend on an external website.